# How to search for constructor / method invocation of given signature in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to search for constructor / method invocation of given signature in IntelliJ?

For example, suppose I have two methods

```
void myMethod(int x, int y);
void myMethod(double x, double y);
```

How to search second one invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is the following: 
Just invoke Find Usages (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) on the second method. If the search results contain both methods, click on the cog and spanner `Settings` icon in the Find tool window. Deselect the `Include overloaded methods` checkbox and click on the Find button.

This settings dialog can also be reached directly via the menu  `Edit | Search | Find Usages Settings...`

Answer (score 1):

For reference I'm giving another option - structural search (Edit > Find > Search > Search Structurally).

The template you need is something like this:
$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$)

In "Edit Variables" dialog you need to adjust "MethodCall" to be "myMethod", "Parameter" count to be 2 and its "Expression type" to be "double"